# подсчет полей выдает NaN

Tags: javascript, jquery

Делаю калькулятор значений из полей формы. Должны подсчитываться горизонтальные значения и потом их значения складываться. Все как бы работает, но плохо... Во время подсчета в остальных полях появляются NaN и общую сумму подсчитывает только после того как что то введу в поле... Не могди бы помочь разобраться, как хотя бы избежать NaN?

```
var $form = $('#plantroom_details'),
  $summands = $form.find('.to_sum_total'),
  $sumDisplay = $('#total-cost-details');

  $form.delegate('.to_sum_total', 'change', function ()
  {
      var sum = 0;
      $summands.each(function ()
      {
          var value = Number($(this).val());
          if (!isNaN(value)) sum += value;
      });

      $sumDisplay.val(sum);
  });


  $(document).ready(function() {
     $('.form-control').change(function(e)  {

          var foundation_m3 = 0;
          var foundation_cost = 0;
          var foundation_width = parseFloat($('#foundation-width').val());
          var foundation_length = parseFloat($('#foundation-length').val());
          var foundation_depth = parseFloat($('#foundation-depth').val());
          foundation_m3 = foundation_width*foundation_length*foundation_depth;
          foundation_cost = foundation_m3*500;
          $('#foundation-m3').val(foundation_m3);
          $('#foundation-cost').val(foundation_cost);

          var walls_m2 = 0;
          var walls_cost = 0;
          var walls_width = parseFloat($('#walls-width').val());
          var walls_length = parseFloat($('#walls-length').val());
          var walls_structure = parseFloat($('#walls-structure').val());
          walls_m2 = walls_width*walls_length*walls_structure;
          walls_cost = walls_m2*200;
          $('#walls-m2').val(walls_m2);
          $('#walls-cost').val(walls_cost);



      });
     });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/qt6o0q6w/

Comment: `parseFloat('')` -> `NaN`

Comment: Вы передаёте в функцию `parseFloat` пустую строку. В этом случае функция логично возвращает `NaN`. Когда в арифметических операциях участвует `NaN`, результатом тоже будет `NaN`. Вы можете добавить проверку `isNaN` и вместо `NaN` присваивать например `0`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам нужно добавить проверку полей. Если поле пустое, но оно не должно брать из него значение:
https://jsfiddle.net/yuri_spivak/qt6o0q6w/1/

```
var $form = $('#plantroom_details'),
      $summands = $form.find('.to_sum_total'),
      $sumDisplay = $('#total-cost-details');

      $form.delegate('.to_sum_total', 'change', function ()
      {
          var sum = 0;
          $summands.each(function ()
          {
              var value = Number($(this).val());
              if (!isNaN(value)) sum += value;
          });

          $sumDisplay.val(sum);
      });


      $(document).ready(function() {
         $('.form-control').change(function(e)  {

              var foundation_m3 = 0;
              var foundation_cost = 0;
              var foundation_width;
              var foundation_length;
              var foundation_depth;
              if($('#foundation-width').val() == ''){foundation_width = 1}else{foundation_width = parseFloat($('#foundation-width').val())};
              if($('#foundation-length').val() == ''){foundation_length = 1}else{foundation_length = parseFloat($('#foundation-length').val())};
              if($('#foundation-depth').val() == ''){foundation_depth = 1}else{foundation_depth = parseFloat($('#foundation-depth').val())};

              foundation_m3 = foundation_width*foundation_length*foundation_depth;
              foundation_cost = foundation_m3*500;
              $('#foundation-m3').val(foundation_m3);
              $('#foundation-cost').val(foundation_cost);

              var walls_m2 = 0;
              var walls_cost = 0;
              var walls_width;
              var walls_length;
              var walls_structure;
              if($('#walls-width').val() == ''){walls_width = 1}else{walls_width = parseFloat($('#walls-width').val())};
              if($('#walls-length').val() == ''){walls_length = 1}else{walls_length = parseFloat($('#walls-length').val())};
              if($('#walls-structure').val() == ''){walls_structure = 1}else{walls_structure = parseFloat($('#walls-structure').val())};

              walls_m2 = walls_width*walls_length*walls_structure;
              walls_cost = walls_m2*200;
              $('#walls-m2').val(walls_m2);
              $('#walls-cost').val(walls_cost);

          });
         });
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, а не могли бы вы еще помочь с общим подсчетом полей Cost в Total. Когда я там руками пишу значения он их считает, а когда они сами туда попадают из горизонтальных полей, то Total не подсчитывается

Comment: @akasergej, а как оно должно подсчитывать? Я ввожу все данные и Total с Cost нормально высчитывается

Comment: $form.delegate('.to_sum_total' поменял на $form.delegate('.form-control' теперь и Тотал обнавляется. Спасибо еще раз за исправленый код, спасли меня! :)

Comment: @akasergej, пусть у вас больше не будет причин к нам обращаться :)